# Building/Loading JavaScript on per page basis in the browser

Tags: javascript

Looking for recommendations here. My situation is this...I have a set of JavaScript files that run multiple analytics and event tracking tasks on our corporate web pages.  Depending on which page, the tasks will vary.  What I am looking to do is build one (or maybe a couple of) JavaScript files on the fly once the page is determined.  My repo is currently 6 JS files, but I am refactoring to organize those by use, and with some new requirements, the number of files will grow to potentially 20+.  So, basically, will build the one or two JS files from the 20 that I have in the repo.

I've been looking at REACT as that is what we use for another application, but don't need to build/serve any HTML or CSS, so it's a bit overkill.  I do not have access to the web server, so anything that would need to tie into that is out.  I've been looking at RequireJS, but have been asked to not use or inject jQuery, so that's not going to work.  At this point, I'm trying to figure out if there is a pure JavaScript solution that will do what I need.

If there is additional information I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: you can build a simple server script to bundle (and cache) your files according to url params. then you can just list the packages you need in the url of a single script tag. ex: http://danml.com/js/?jsmin,download3,ready from http://danml.com/js/

Comment: The issue with this is that I have no way of editing the src value.  I have one named JS file and that value can not be changed from page to page.  I've been looking at WebPack, and it looks promising, but it sounds like the packages will need to be pre-built and served based on the URL.

Comment: Your single named JS file can always dynamically create other `<script>` tags and reference the needed JavaScript files according to the current `window.location.href`